# Using Vim :make with quickfix ends up creating a new file when error is in header

Tags: vim, makefile, buffer

I've got a setup with Vim where I can compile my C/C++ code using `:make` and compilation errors are automatically shown in a quickfix window using the following lines [(from the Vim wiki)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_open_the_quickfix_window_on_:make) in my `./vimrc`:

```
" Automatically open, but do not go to (if there are errors) the quickfix /
" location list window, or close it when is has become empty. 
"
" Note: Must allow nesting of autocmds to enable any customizations for quickfix
" buffers. 
" Note: Normally, :cwindow jumps to the quickfix window if the command opens it
" (but not if it's already open). However, as part of the autocmd, this doesn't
" seem to happen. 
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow
```

Now this setup works well if there is an **error in a .cpp file**, as the output from make is correctly parsed:

```
$ make
g++    -c -o IsingMain.o IsingMain.cpp
g++    -c -o LatticeModel.o LatticeModel.cpp
LatticeModel.cpp: In member function ‘void LatticeModel::initialiseSystem()’:
LatticeModel.cpp:18:25: error: ‘sirand’ was not declared in this scope
```

i.e. vim correctly switches to `LatticeModel.cpp`.

---

However if the error is in the **header file**, the make output is misinterpreted, and vim switches/creates a new buffer (for the following example `make` output) with name "`In file included from IsingMain.cpp`", clearly erroneously assuming that this is the file with the error (in fact the error is in LatticeModel.h):

```
$ make
g++    -c -o IsingMain.o IsingMain.cpp
In file included from IsingMain.cpp:2:0:
LatticeModel.h:31:5: error: ‘Zvoid’ does not name a type
```

Running make from the commandline works perfectly well, it's just an issue with quickfix misreading it's output. Any help greatly appreciated, let me know if any part of this is confusing. Thanks

**EDIT**: It seems to be something to do with with an incorrect errorformat (as described in  [this thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/vim-errorformat-requires-updating-for-gcc-4-5-unreleased-td1205444.html).)

**EDIT 2**: Temporary fix found by ignoring the make output line that starts with "In file included from" using [this technique](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/msg/ed4f258f5b4b9749).

Comment: Several questions: 
- What file does it end up creating? ; 
- what is the current path? and the paths of your files? ; 
- what version of vim are you using (cygwin or win32)? ; 
- what version of gcc are you using (TDM/mingw or cygwin)? ;
- from where are you launching vim (bash or windows explorer)?

Comment: @Luc Hermitte - It ends up creating the buffer (doesn't actually create the file unless saved) with the full name `In file included from IsingMain.cpp` (spaces included). I'm using Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu, with gcc 4.5.2. The [makefile might also be useful](http://pastebin.com/dW069zT8)? Vim is being run from the same directory as the source files and the makefile.

Comment: OK, that name is important. It seems like the error message introduction is interpreted as a filename. I would ask on vim mailing list. It's the best place to do so. If a solution exists, this way it could be integrated into the next version of vim.
Otherwise, have a look at `:h 'efm'`, the solution lies in the tweaking of this option if you which to solve it on your own (i'm not very good at tweaking this option ^^')

Comment: @Luc Hermitte - ok interesting. the [errorformat for both .cpp and .h files](http://pastebin.com/vN0SZZ9g) seems to include a line which ignores lines starting with "In file included with", so not sure why that's not working. trying to decode that horrid string now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I have still not found a proper solution, the workaround suggested here: http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/msg/ed4f258f5b4b9749
seems to work for the time being.

```
set errorformat^=%-GIn\ file\ included\ %.%#
```

**EDIT**: see also [Vim tries to jump to nonexistent file after :make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427141/vim-tries-to-jump-to-nonexistent-file-after-make)