# Vim tries to jump to nonexistent file after :make

Tags: vim, gcc, makefile

I'm using `:make` from `vim` and ending up jumping to the file with issues.

Recently, at least I noticed with `gcc 4.6.1`, `vim` jumps to incorrect file/line because it goes to the first reported line which has `"In file included from ABC.h|5| 0,"` and there is no file called `"In file included from ABC.h"`.

There is a solution to extract just the file name from the above line, `ABC.h` in this case, but that does not solve the problem as the problematic file is only included there.

Usually the next line indicates where the issue is and that's where I would like to jump:

```
MyDir/FGH.h|56 col 32| error: 'bad bad thing happened here'
```

Is there a known fix for this in `vim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a bug that is solved on new versions of Vim: [Bug report logs - #62169](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=621693).

You can use the following setting to solve the problem without upgrading Vim:

```
  set errorformat^=%-GIn\ file\ included\ from\ %f:%l:%c:,%-GIn\ file
           \\ included\ from\ %f:%l:%c\\,,%-GIn\ file\ included\ from\ %f
           \:%l:%c,%-GIn\ file\ included\ from\ %f:%l
```

(setting extracted from latest Vim source code, from file [src/option.h](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/option.h))

Answer (score 4):

`:make!` doesn't jump to the first result.

Comment: that's not the actual problem, though it _is_ the workaround I use

Comment: But I want to jump to the first result! Thanks though for pointing it out, I've always wanted to look for this but just couldn't find enough time ... mostly I want to jump into the first error/warning (and fix it) ...

Comment: +1 for showing me the option which I never had time to look for :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with slight differences in the errorformat required for recent versions of gcc.

I believe this was mentioned in C++ Lounge (chat) the other day, and an errorformat was posted that supposedly works better. *I haven't tested that it does*:

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=errorformat&room=10

  ```
   errorformat=%*[^"]"%f"%*\D%l: %m,"%f"%*\D%l: %m,%-G%f:%l: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once,%-G%f:%l: for each function it appears in.),%-GInfile included from %f:%l:%c:,%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c\,,%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c,%-GIn file included from %f:%l,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:%c,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l\,,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l,%f:%l:%c:%m,%f(%l):%m,%f:%l:%m,"%f"\, line %l%*\D%c%*[^ ] %m,%D%*\a[%*\d]: Entering directory `%f',%X%*\a[%*\d]: Leaving directory `%f',%D%*\a: Entering directory `%f',%X%*\a: Leaving directory `%f',%DMaking %*\a in %f,%f|%l| %m
  ```